# How to Highlight Points Which is Not in Data?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to highlight certain points, but this is not in the original data set.

Suppose I'm working with this dataset.

```
library(gcookbook) # To use 'heightweight' dataset
head(heightweight)
  sex ageYear ageMonth heightIn weightLb
1   f   11.92      143     56.3     85.0
2   f   12.92      155     62.3    105.0
3   f   12.75      153     63.3    108.0
4   f   13.42      161     59.0     92.0
5   f   15.92      191     62.5    112.5
6   f   14.25      171     62.5    112.0
ggplot(heightweight, aes(x = ageYear, y = heightIn, color = sex)) + geom_point()
```

[ggplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/avK4B.png)
No problem till here, but I want to highlight the mean points for each group(sex).

```
female = subset(heightweight, select = c(ageYear, heightIn), subset = (sex == 'f'))
male = subset(heightweight, select = c(ageYear, heightIn), subset = (sex == 'm'))
female_a = mean(female[,1]); female_a
[1] 13.70063
female_h = mean(female[,2]); female_h
[1] 60.52613
male_a = mean(male[,1]); male_a
[1] 13.64752
male_h = mean(male[,2]); male_h
[1] 62.06
```

Clearly, these points are not in the dataset, but I want to highlight these points in the original ggplot by thickered dots.

Any ideas?

Comment: `gghighlighter` might be useful in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to precalculate it in the dataset:

```
heightweight <- heightweight %>%
  group_by(sex) %>%
  mutate(
    ageyear = mean(ageYear),
    heightin = mean(heightIn)
  ) %>% ungroup()
```

The plot:

```
ggplot(heightweight, aes(x = ageYear, y = heightIn, color = sex)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_point(aes(x = ageyear, y = heightin), size = 5)
```

This could be part of the pipeline, like:

```
heightweight %>%
  group_by(sex) %>%
  mutate(
    ageyear = mean(ageYear),
    heightin = mean(heightIn)
  ) %>% ungroup() %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = ageYear, y = heightIn, color = sex)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_point(aes(x = ageyear, y = heightin), size = 5)
```

The advantage of this approach is that it saves some coding time/space and you don't need to transition (from `base` to `ggplot2` for example), also colors are automatically the same as for the other dots (split by `sex`).

I've only increased the size for the `mean` dots that you expect to see. There could be of course further tweaks, depending on how you'd like to plot your data.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it that way :

```
 plot_missing_mean_value =    ggplot(heightweight, aes(x = ageYear, y = heightIn, color = sex)) + geom_point()+
      geom_point(aes(female_a, female_h,size = 5), colour="blue")+
      geom_point(aes(male_a, male_h,size = 5), colour="green")
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @arg0naut, but avoiding series of overlapped means:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gcookbook)

data(heightweight)

heightweight %>%
  group_by(sex) %>%
  summarize(avga = mean(ageYear), avgh = mean(heightIn)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = avga, y = avgh, colour = sex, label = sex)) +
  geom_point(size = 5, shape = 7, show.legend = F) +
  geom_point(data = heightweight, aes(x = ageYear, y = heightIn), alpha = .5) +
  #ggthemes::theme_tufte() +
  labs(x = 'Age (years)', y = 'Height (in)')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much as well! Finally have done it! Sorry that I can give only 1 check..